# Graphics upgrade on Centos 7

Tags: centos, drivers, graphics, gpu, intel

I possibly have a problem with my intel g33 driver on Centos 7. How can i dowload and install it?
"sudo yum upgrade" command returns "No packages marked for update"

Comment: "I possibly have a problem"... which is?

Comment: i cant update OpenGL from 1.4 to at least 3.6(or newer) on my Linux computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux doesn't have a concept of "drivers" per se. What we have are kernel modules which are tied to the kernel release. There are some separate entities, e.g. X.org and Mesa which could be considered "drivers" as well but they are controlled by your distro. You can perfectly update the kernel, X.org and Mesa on your own though (which is not exactly easy but doable).

G33 is quite an old device (released in ~2007) and must be properly supported even by the kernel in CentOS 7. What are the exact issues that you have? Please edit your question and add more information.

Comment: Thank you. I installed Centos 7 on another computer with modern gpu(i5 9300 gtx 1050) and the error i had in my JavaFx application with Intel g33 gpu "Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION(major.minor) = 1.4" dissapeared.

Comment: G33 indeed features an outdated OpenGL implementation (version 1.4) which might not be sufficient for recent applications: https://www.intel.com/assets/pdf/prodbrief/317311.pdf

Comment: yes. It's the problem i find solution for